# Convert hotkey in CHotKeyCtrl from virtual code to string and backward

Tags: mfc, hotkeys

I have `CHotKeyCtrl` and I can get virtual Key Code and modifiers from it. I also can call `CHotKeyCtrl::GetHotKeyName` to get string view of this hotkey - I can show this string to user and store it in my XML config file. But how to convert this string backward to virtual key code and modifiers? I do not want to save in XML just virtual keycode and midifiers in `WORD` form (it's not very informative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no support out of the box to convert a hot key name into a virtual key code + modifiers pair, mainly because [GetHotKeyName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tk8xd3c.aspx) returns a *localized* name. That name comes from the keyboard driver and will vary from one Windows installation to the other.

Since [WM_SETHOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646284.aspx) takes a virtual key code and its modifiers, packed into a `WPARAM`, you can build that value and store it in your XML settings in order to avoid using two elements / attributes. You can also include the hot key name for easier reading, but storing only that name will not give you the information required to send `WM_SETHOTKEY` afterwards.